# Bind to an Element Which Does Not Exist (with no user interaction/click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, petite-vue

I've been added to an existing project (jQuery, petite-vue ...) and I'm trying to add [this simple WYSIWYG](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation) to a form textarea.

The textarea does not exist on page load. This is the template code which shows how it's added dynamically. The `forum` object is the result of an async GET wait fetch request.

```
<div class="row" v-if="forum.currentGroup && JSON.stringify(forum.currentGroup) != '{}'">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
        <form @submit.prevent="forum.addThread" method="post" class="no-recaptcha mb-2">
            <textarea rows="4"
                      id="summernote"
                      name="question"
                      placeholder="{{ 'forum.ask_your_question' | trans }}"
                      class="form-control mb-2 question"
                      required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary small float-end">{{ 'forum.send' | trans }}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

As per the summernote install direction, the following command simply doesn't work;

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
```

I also tried to access the element when receiveing a response from the `fetch` request, but it is always logging `null` in the code below;

```
        try {
            let response = await fetch(` ... the url ... `, {
                method: 'GET',
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const json = await response.json();
                if (json.success) {
                    ...

                    let thing = document.getElementById('summernote');
                    console.log(thing);

                    $('#summernote').summernote();
```

To try and find out what's going on with the document, I ran the following code;

```
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        console.log('load');
    });

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
        console.log(document.readyState);
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        console.log('DOMContentLoaded');
    });
```

The console log for that code is;

```
complete
load
```

The `DOMContentLoaded` listener never outputs to console. I tried using an `on('load')` but it never gets called;

```
    $(document).on('load', '.question', function() {
        alert('blah');
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
```

I have to render the WYSIWYG without user interaction ... when the textarea is added to the page, it should render the wysiwyg editor.

Any ideas? I've been at this for a couple of days and am at a loss.

Comment: `$('#summernote').summernote();` would need to go in the "success" function of your async GET operation, after the form element has been created.

Comment: Thanks James, but the element rendering is controlled by the `v-if` directive on the `<div>`. You did remind me i also tried accessing the element after recieving a response from the async request, but as you'd expect, it also doesn't work. I added that to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom component with the `<textarea>` inside, and initialise the plugin on mount:

```js
const SummernoteView = {
    mounted() {
        $("#summernote").summernote();
    },
    template: `
        <textarea rows="4"
            id="summernote"
            name="question"
            placeholder="{{ 'forum.ask_your_question' | trans }}"
            class="form-control mb-2 question"
            required></textarea>
    `,
};

export default SummernoteView;
```

Remember to import and declare it in the parent component:

```js
import SummernoteView from './SummernoteView';

// your parent component
{
  data() { ... },
  methods: { ... }
  components: {
    'summernote-view': SummernoteView
  }
}
```

In your template:

```html
<div class="row" v-if="forum.currentGroup && JSON.stringify(forum.currentGroup) != '{}'">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
        <form @submit.prevent="forum.addThread" method="post" class="no-recaptcha mb-2">
            <summernote-view/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary small float-end">{{ 'forum.send' | trans }}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

More on [Vue Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component).

Comment: thank you for the help. You got me on the right track. Apparently petite differs a lot for this usecase. I would post my result, but it means nothing when following the petite docs, or other online examples (god know what i've got myself into with this project). [Here is some petite-vue info](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#examples) for others who may come across this post.